# Can't find -lz, when zlib is on LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: compiling, make, cmake

By the amount of posts I have check, I have run into a common problem people finds when compiling. **Make** exist with the error:

```
/home/iprada/bin/miniconda/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
```

I have try to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to places where I have versions of zlib, for example:

```
/home/iprada/bin/miniconda/lib/
```

I have also try to install zlib by myself, and do the same, add that to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but again, no success.

This is the whole error message just in case:

```
Linking CXX executable ../../../bin/bayesTyper
/home/iprada/bin/miniconda/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
/home/iprada/bin/miniconda/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/bayesTyper/CMakeFiles/bayesTyper.dir/build.make:727: ../bin/bayesTyper] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:231: src/bayesTyper/CMakeFiles/bayesTyper.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:76: all] Error 2
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: do you have this specfic file name: `libz.so` in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` path?

Comment: I have this set of files on LD_LIBRARY_PATH: "libz.a  libz.so  libz.so.1  libz.so.1.2.11  pkgconfig"